# Import js function to html

Tags: html, reactjs

i am trying to learn react

js
and my html file
which is at path public/login.html
and
my js scipt file for button click is at src/login.js file

when i run this code the function is not being called console shows LoginClick() not defined
between i am using react js

html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>`your text`
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/login.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--`your text`
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div class="login">
            <label for="uname">Username</label>
            <input type="tex" id="uname"><br>
            <label for="pwd">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="pwd"><br>
            <button id="login" onclick={LoginClick}>Login</button>
        </div> 
  <script src="../src/login.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

my js

```
function LoginClick() {
return alert("hey")
}
```

Comment: I think you did not understand the concept of React. Why did you put the `form` code in your `html`? React should have extensions of `js` or `jsx` and you need to create components and use it.

Comment: This is almost not a React question, so there's already a comment of what I was going to write. I suggest you to watch some YouTube tutorial first or read through Reactjs docs.

Answer (score -1):

Just change the {LoginClick} to LoginClick().

Comment: As he/she said, he/she is trying to learn react but the code isn't written in react and it's completely wrong.